# How do I position a geeklet on my second monitor?

Tags: macos, multiple-monitors, geektool

I have three monitors, and I want to use the left one to display the time atop my wallpaper. However, since my center monitor is my main monitor, geeklets are constrained to that one. **How do I move the geeklet to my left monitor?**

[<sub>Screenshots</sub>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mPgjd.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to move a geeklet to another display you can just drag it to the location of your choice. *Make sure you have the GeekTool Preferences open so you can select and drag geeklets.*

If you would like to position geeklets programatically this can be done with Applescript. Here's a link that should help. https://gist.github.com/seansu4you87/9595069

Imagine the combined space of all your monitors as a single workspace with 0,0 being the top left-hand corner of your main display (the display containing the menu bar in the Arrangement pane of the Displays Preference Pane). ***Displays arranged to the left of the main display will have negative x-axis co-ordinates.*** The tops of the displays 0 on the y-axis.
Using the link above I created applescripts to rearrange my geeklets for my various display configurations (Solo laptop, second display to the right, second display to the left, and two external displays, one on either side).

**Addendum:** For the sake of clarity I should have added that the co-ordinates shown in the GeekTool Preferences window for geeklets positioned on external displays will confusingly show co-ordinates based on 0,0 being the top left of the geeklet's display and must be converted, as described above, to work with AppleScript.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer! It's been years since I used GeekTool; I uninstalled it a month or so after asking this question since it seemed like there was no answer. If I ever start using this again, I'll try out your answer and get back to you!